# Prolog simple generator

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm trying to learn myself Prolog and need a little help.

Could someone solve and explain this problem:

Define a p(A, M/N, K/L), which generates all possible rational fractions M/N and K/L, where:

```
N>M>0, K>L>0, (M/N)*(K/L) = 2 and (M+K)<A
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is your experience with prolog?

Comment: Having someone else solve the entire problem and explaining it to you isn't a good way to learn Prolog. The best way to learn Prolog is to start with very simple problems, working them out yourself and asking questions where you get stuck, first. Then moving to more complex ones.

Comment: Should that read `M>N>0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not that clear to me, I am rather guessing which values should be known and which are asked. So I will rather use `library(clpfd)` where I do not have to make such considerations myself.

> ```
> N>M>0, K>L>0, (M/N)*(K/L) = 2 and (M+K)<A
> ```

```
p(A, M/N, K/L) :-
   N #> M, M #> 0,
   K #> L, L #> 0,
   M+K #< A,
   (M/N) * (K/L) #= 2.

?- 3/2 #= F.
   F = 1.
?- (3/2)*2 #= F.
   F = 2.
```

Oh, clpfd is on the integers so fractions are truncated. I need some algebra first, multiplying both sides with `(N*L)` (they are both not 0...):

```
p(A, M/N, K/L) :-
   N #> M, M #> 0,
   K #> L, L #> 0,
   M+K #< A,
   M*K #= 2*N*L.

?- p(A, M/N, K/L).
   A in 4..sup, M+K+ -1*A#=< -1, M in 1..sup,
   M#=<N+ -1, M*K#=_A, N in 2..sup, 2*N#=_B,
   _B in 4..sup, _B*L#=_A, L in 1..sup, L#=<K+ -1,
   K in 2..sup, _A in 4..sup.
```

So Prolog says: Yes! That is true <sup><sub>provided all this very fine print is true</sub></sup>. The first line is the most interesting `A in 4..sup` which means that there is no upper bound for `A`. To get concrete solutions, `A` must be known:

```
?- A #= 10, p(A, M/N, K/L).
   A = 10, M in 1..7, M+K#=_A, M#=<N+ -1,
   M*K#=_B, K in 2..8, L#=<K+ -1, L in 1..7,
   _C*L#=_B, _C in 4..56, 2*N#=_C, N in 2..28,
   _B in 4..56, _A in 3..9.
```

Not enough! But now `K, L, M, N` have all **finite domains**, so we can enumerate them using `labeling([], [K,L,M,N])`.

```
?- A = 10, p(A,M/N,K/L),labeling([],[M,N,K,L]).
   A = 10, M = L, L = 1, N = 2, K = 4
;  A = 10, M = 1, N = L, L = 2, K = 8
;  A = 10, M = L, L = 1, N = 3, K = 6
;  ... .
```